# Read CSV as Text file and tokenize it

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tokenize

I had a previous question that had too many components so I was urged to break down the task. First I am to Read my CSV as a text file and tokenize the data inside. When I do I get an error.

```
csv_file = 'Annual Budget.csv'
txt_file = 'Annual Budget.txt'
with open(txt_file, 'w') as my_output_file:
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as my_input_file:
        for row in csv_file.reader(my_input_file):
            my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n')
```

This is the error (output) :

```
line 46, in <module>
    for row in csv_file.reader(my_input_file):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

What does this mean and how can one solve this?

Comment: `csv-file` is a string, not a file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) to instantiate a [reader](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object.

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but the following code will create from your CSV file a  text file with the cells row-wise joined by spaces:

```
import csv

csv_file = 'Annual Budget.csv'
txt_file = 'Annual Budget.txt'
with open(txt_file, 'w') as my_output_file:
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as my_input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(my_input_file)
        for row in reader:
            my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n')
```

Note, that the instantiation of the CSV reader object (`reader`) takes the *file*, not the *file name* as parameter.